# Map the JSON key and update the value in another JSON using angular2

Tags: angular

I have a Angular 2 form values which is generated after form(form values) submit in the following way,

### form data:

```
   {
      "LoyaltyNumber": "mal",
      "CardAcceptorName": "John",
    }
```

And i have another JSON object which we need to send final values to server.

```
{
  "LoyaltyNumber": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": "" 
  },
"CardAcceptorName": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": ""
  }
}
```

And, i want to update `value` from second JSON with the value coming in the first JSON.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate over the keys of your first json object. `Object.keys()` returns a string array containing the key names. So we can call `.forEach()` on that result. In the foreach method we can use the key to access the child object in `secondJsonObj`.

```
Object.keys(firstJsonObj).forEach(key => {
    if (secondJsonObj[key]) {
        secondJsonObj[key].value = firstJsonObj[key]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first JSON is assigned to firstJsonObj, second JSON is assigned to secondJsonObj;

```
firstJsonObj = {
  "LoyaltyNumber": "mal",
  "CardAcceptorName": "John",
};

secondJsonObj = {
  "LoyaltyNumber": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": "" 
  },
"CardAcceptorName": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": ""
  }
};
```

You can assign values like this

```
secondJsonObj.LoyaltyNumber.value = firstJsonObj.LoyaltyNumber;
secondJsonObj.CardAcceptorName.value = firstJsonObj.CardAcceptorName;
```

If you want dynamic.

```
Object.keys(firstJsonObj).forEach(function(key){
      secondJsonObj[key]. value = firstJsonObj[key];
 });
```

Comment: but it should be dynamic, i do not know how many values are exists. can u please help on this in dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var json1 = {
      "LoyaltyNumber": "mal",
      "CardAcceptorName": "John"
    };

var json2 = {
  "LoyaltyNumber": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": "" 
  },
"CardAcceptorName": {
    "tcId": "PREQ_001",
    "msgSeq": 1,
    "value": ""
  }
};

json2.LoyaltyNumber.value = json1.LoyaltyNumber;
json2.CardAcceptorName.value= json1.CardAcceptorName;

console.log(JSON.stringify(json2));
```

**Output:**

{"LoyaltyNumber":{"tcId":"PREQ_001","msgSeq":1,"value":"mal"},"CardAcceptorName":{"tcId":"PREQ_001","msgSeq":1,"value":"John"}}